# When casting an int64 to uint64, is the sign retained?

Tags: go, time, integer, unsigned-integer

I have an int64 variable which contains a negative number and I wish to subtract it from an uint64 variable which contains a positive number:

```
var endTime uint64
now := time.Now().Unix()
endTime = uint64(now)
var interval int64
interval = -3600
endTime = endTime + uint64(interval)
```

The above code appears to work but I wonder if I can rely on this. I am surprised, being new to Go, that after casting a negative number to uint64 that it remains negative -- I had planned to subtract the now positive value (after casting) to get what I wanted.

Comment: Well, first `uint(a)` is not a cast in Go but a type conversion which just re-interprets the bits of a a being a uint. Now uints are just bit patterns and are neither positive nor negative and adding them is a bit operation resulting in a new bit pattern if you interpret this bit pattern as a signed integer then you'll see a subtraction happening because, well, that's how two's complement works. Tip: Do not use uints for numbers unless you feel comfortable with two's complement.

Comment: Formally the answer would be: "Yes, you can rely on the language following the language spec."  which is a bit of nonsense answer.

Comment: Go doesn't have casting at all.

Answer (score 7):

Converting a signed number to an unsigned number will not remain negative, it can't, as the valid range of unsigned types doesn't include negative numbers. If you print `uint(interval)`, you will certainly see a positive number printed.

What you experience is deterministic and you can rely on it (but it doesn't mean you should). It is the result of Go (and most other programming languages) storing signed integer types using the [2's completement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation.

What this means is that in case of negative numbers, using `n` bit, the value `-x` (where `x` is positive) is stored as the binary representation of the positive value `2^n - x`. This has the advantage that numbers can be added bitwise, and the result will be correct regardless of whether they are negative or positive.

So when you have a signed negative number, it is basically stored in memory like if you would subtract its absolute value from `0`. Which means that if you convert a negative, signed value to unsigned, and you add that to an unsigned value, the result will be correct because overflow will happen, in a useful way.

Converting a value of type `int64` to `uint64` does not change the memory layout, only the type. So what 8 bytes the `int64` had, the converted `uint64` will have those same 8 bytes. And as mentioned above, the representation stored in those 8 bytes is the bit pattern identical to the bit pattern of value `0 - abs(x)`. So the result of the conversion will be a number that you would get if you would subtract `abs(x)` from `0`, in the unsigned world. Yes, this won't be negative (as the type is unsigned), instead it will be a "big" number, counting down from the max value of the `uint64` type. But if you add an `y` number bigger than `abs(x)` to this "big" number, overflow will happen, and the result will be like `y - abs(x)`.

See this simple example demonstrating what's happening (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Ei9IAqxDnBv)):

```
a := uint8(100)
b := int8(-10)
fmt.Println(uint8(b)) // Prints 226 which is: 0 - 10 = 256 - 10
a = a + uint8(b)
fmt.Println(a)        // Prints 90 which is: 100 + 226 = 326 = 90
                      //           after overflow: 326 - 256 = 90
```

As mentioned above, you should not rely on this, as this may cause confusion. If you intend to work with negative numbers, then use signed types.

And if you work with a code base that already uses `uint64` values, then do a subtraction instead of addition, using `uint64` values:

```
interval := uint64(3600)
endTime -= interval
```

Also note that if you have [`time.Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) values, you should take advantage of its [`Time.Add()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Add) method:

```
func (t Time) Add(d Duration) Time
```

You may specify a [`time.Duration`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) to add to the time, which may be negative if you want to go back in time, like this:

```
t := time.Now()
t = t.Add(-3600 * time.Second)
```

`time.Duration` is more expressive: we see the value we specified above uses seconds explicitly.

Comment: The existing code uses already uint64 to represent time. I am not sure the motivation behind this or whether it is safe to change the variable types.

Comment: @Jeff Then you may continue to use `uint64` type, but then do a subtraction, not addition, e.g. `interval := uint64(3600)` and then `endTime -= interval`.

Comment: the code is over simplified somewhat. interval can be a positive or negative value, specified by the user on the command line. If it is negative, it is added to the end time to get actually start time; if it is positive it is added to the start time to get end time. so i may be missing a better way of doing it but that is why I added interval.

Comment: @icza Won't there be a overflow when converting a signed number to an unsigned ?

Comment: @Metalhead1247 Conversion does not "incur" overflow. Conversion does not change the memory representation, just the type. Overflow may be the result of some arithmetic operation, a conversion is not that.