# Golang shift operator conversion

Tags: go, type-conversion, operator-keyword

I can not understand in golang how `1<<s` return `0` if `var s uint = 33`.
But `1<<33` return `8589934592`. 
How a shift operator conversion end up with a value of 0.

I'm reading the language specification and stuck in this section:
https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators

Specifically this paragraph from docs:

> "The right operand in a shift expression must have unsigned integer
>   type or be an untyped constant representable by a value of type uint.
>   **If the left operand of a non-constant shift expression is an untyped
>   constant, it is first implicitly converted to the type it would assume
>   if the shift expression were replaced by its left operand alone**."

Some example from official Golang docs:

```
var s uint = 33
var i = 1<<s                  // 1 has type int
var j int32 = 1<<s            // 1 has type int32; j == 0
var k = uint64(1<<s)          // 1 has type uint64; k == 1<<33
```

**Update:**

Another very related question, with an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
v := int16(4336)
    fmt.Println(int8(v))
}
```

This program return `-16`

How does the number `4336` become `-16` in converting `int16` to `int8`

Comment: I corrected it in the example

Comment: In this case, the answer is "because sign bit". I can't quote the spec at the moment, but apparently this conversion is done by discarding the higher byte and interpreting the rest as a signed 8-bit int. Signed integers have a thing called sign bit. If this bit is 1, the number is negative.

Comment: very helpful info. it may help me get it. So 4336 in binary is 1000011110000
and 16 is 10000. -16 is 110000? does sign reserve 2 bits, so what left of int8 is 6 bits and it result in truncating the number 1000011110000 to 10000 (which is 16)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have this:

```
var s uint = 33
fmt.Println(1 << s)
```

Then the quoted part applies:

> If the left operand of a non-constant shift expression is an untyped constant, it is first implicitly converted to the type it would assume if the shift expression were replaced by its left operand alone.

Because `s` is not a constant (it's a variable), therefore `1 >> s` is a non-constant shift expression. And the left operand is `1` which is an untyped constant (e.g. `int(1)` would be a typed constant), so it is converted to a type that it would get if the expression would be simply `1` instead of `1 << s`:

```
fmt.Println(1)
```

In the above, the untyped constant `1` would be converted to `int`, because that is its default type. Default type of constants is in [Spec: Constants:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants)

> An untyped constant has a *default type* which is the type to which the constant is implicitly converted in contexts where a typed value is required, for instance, in a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) such as `i := 0` where there is no explicit type. The default type of an untyped constant is `bool`, `rune`, `int`, `float64`, `complex128` or `string` respectively, depending on whether it is a boolean, rune, integer, floating-point, complex, or string constant.

And the result of the above is architecture dependent. If `int` is 32 bits, it will be `0`. If `int` is 64 bits, it will be `8589934592` (because shifting a `1` bit 33 times will shift it out of a 32-bit `int` number).

On the Go playground, size of `int` is 32 bits (4 bytes). See this example:

```
fmt.Println("int size:", unsafe.Sizeof(int(0)))

var s uint = 33

fmt.Println(1 << s)
fmt.Println(int32(1) << s)
fmt.Println(int64(1) << s)
```

The above outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/jfZWEcZ0105)):

```
int size: 4
0
0
8589934592
```

If I run the above app on my 64-bit computer, the output is:

```
int size: 8
8589934592
0
8589934592
```

Also see [The Go Blog: Constants](https://blog.golang.org/constants) for how constants work in Go.

Note that if you write `1 << 33`, that is not the same, that is not a non-constant shift expression, which your quote applies to: *"the left operand of a non-constant shift expression"*. `1<<33` is a constant shift expression, which is evaluated at "constant space", and the result would be converted to `int` which does not fit into a 32-bit `int`, hence the compile-time error. It works with variables, because variables can overflow. Constants do not overflow:

> Numeric constants represent exact values of arbitrary precision and do not overflow.

See [How does Go perform arithmetic on constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982278/how-does-go-perform-arithmetic-on-constants/38982889#38982889)

**Update:**

Answering your addition: converting from `int16` to `int8` simply keeps the lowest 8 bits. And integers are represented using the [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) format, where the highest bit is `1` if the number is negative.

This is detailed in [Spec: Conversions:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)

> When converting between integer types, if the value is a signed integer, it is sign extended to implicit infinite precision; otherwise it is zero extended. **It is then truncated to fit in the result type's size.** For example, if `v := uint16(0x10F0)`, then `uint32(int8(v)) == 0xFFFFFFF0`. The conversion always yields a valid value; there is no indication of overflow.

So when you convert a `int16` value to `int8`, if source number has a `1` in bit position 7 (8th bit), the result will be negative, even if the source wasn't negative. Similarly, if the source has `0` at bit position 7, the result will be positive, even if the source is negative.

See this example:

```
for _, v := range []int16{4336, -129, 8079} {
    fmt.Printf("Source    : %v\n", v)
    fmt.Printf("Source hex: %4x\n", uint16(v))
    fmt.Printf("Result hex: %4x\n", uint8(int8(v)))
    fmt.Printf("Result    : %4v\n", uint8(int8(v)))
    fmt.Println()
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7Zjx2IVVc01)):

```
Source    : 4336
Source hex: 10f0
Result hex:   f0
Result    :  -16

Source    : -129
Source hex: ff7f
Result hex:   7f
Result    :  127

Source    : 8079
Source hex: 1f8f
Result hex:   8f
Result    : -113
```

See related questions:

[When casting an int64 to uint64, is the sign retained?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50815512/when-casting-an-int64-to-uint64-is-the-sign-retained/50815961#50815961)

[Format printing the 64bit integer -1 as hexadecimal deviates between golang and C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49573389/format-printing-the-64bit-integer-1-as-hexadecimal-deviates-between-golang-and/49574308#49574308)

Comment: Thank for the details. But on google play ground if it typed fmt.Println(1<<33) it gives overflow error for int. But fmt.Println(1 << s) return 0. I can do fmt.Println(int32(1)<<33) or  fmt.Println(int32(1<<33)) it always return overflow error. Something im not able to understand

Comment: @Salimd83 If you write `1 << 33`, that is not the same, that is not a non-constant shift expression, which your quote applies to: _"the left operand of a non-constant shift expression"_. `1<<33` is a constant shift expression, which is evaluated at "constant space", and the result would be converted to `int` which does not fit into a 32-bit `int`. It works with variables, because variables can overflow. Constants do not overflow.

Answer (score 2):

You're building and running the program in 32bit mode (go playground?). In it, int is 32-bit wide and behaves the same as int32.